# Delete VM including storage with python-libvirt

Tags: python, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to write scripts in Python with the [libvirt library](https://pypi.org/project/libvirt-python), but there's one thing I'm currently stuck at.

I can successfully create a VM, set it up how I want it, start it, access it, and shutdown it. I can even delete it again after I no longer need it.

But I haven't yet figured out how to get rid of the VM's disks.

In my "prototype" in Bash, I could just call `virsh undefine <name> --remove-all-storage`. But in all the documentation, I have not yet found a way to trigger this in Python.

Of course I could just do `os.system("virsh undefine ...")` but that's A) a terrible hack and B) it requires virsh to be installed.

Calling `.undefine()` on the domain leaves the vDisk around. I found `.undefineFlags()`, but none of the flags I found seem to be related (1=delete saves, 2=delete snapshots, 4=delete NVRAM; none of which deletes vDisks).

I can call `.XMLDesc()` on the domain and get the full XML, find the defined disks, and get the file path. If my Python script were to run on the same machine as the VMs I could then just call `os.remove()` - but it's not, it's running on a remote machine.

The `virsh` command is able to delete the disks through the libvirt remote connection, so I know it has to be possible somehow. But even looking at the source code where virsh's `--remove-all-storage` is defined, I'm still confused.

The application seems to call `virStorageVolWipe` for a secure delete, or `virStorageVolDelete` to just remove the disk. That would require me to get a Python `virStorageVol` object to be able to call its [`delete()` method](https://github.com/holen/opensource/blob/1227d187271f95a779482af288e64ec08f394a70/webvirtmgr/libvirt.py#L2988).

But then how do I get this object? I found tons of references to a "storage pool" that I could iterate through to find the paths, or I could even get the path to the storage disk from the VM's XML; but that doesn't give me that object so I can call `delete()` on it.

Do I really need to loop through all Storage Pools, then loop through all Volumes in said Pool, then somehow manually figure out for each of these Volumes if it's connected to the VM I want to delete, just to be able to fully delete a VM when I'm done using it? Also, I believe it's in theory possible to have a Volume that's not in any Storage Pool, so that wouldn't help either ...

Why is there no `virDomainGetVolumes`? I found `virDomainGetBlockInfo` but that just returns the paths and types, not a `virStorageVol` object. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was thinking way too complicated.

I can get the host's paths to the VM disks by parsing the XML returned by `.XMLDesc()`, and then I can call `.storageVolLookupByPath()` (which I apparently missed earlier) to get a `storageVol` object to delete:

```py
domain = conn.lookupByName("my-vm-name")
domain_xml = domain.XMLDesc()

for disk_xml_element in ElementTree.fromstring(domain_xml).findall("devices/disk"):
  for src in disk_xml_element.findall("source"):
    disk = virt_conn.storageVolLookupByPath(src.get("file"))
    disk.delete()
```